# What is this 'key' and getBooleanExtra() doing here in android?

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to understand this code segment from my book for android:

```
public class CheatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.britannia.android.quiz.answer_is_true";
private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;
private TextView mAnswerTextView;
private Button mShowAnswer;

public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue) {
    Intent i = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    return i;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

    mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);

    mAnswerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);

    mShowAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showAnswerButton);
    mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
            }
            else {
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

What is the string `EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE` for? I don't understand it's purpose. And in the `getBooleanExtra()` it has two arguments, which is the string mentioned above and a value of false. Why is it false? The purpose of this activity is meant to show the correct answer for a true or false question. Why is it that the value is false and not true?

Thanks.

Comment: If the book is presenting code to you, and the book is not explaining that code, you need a better book. :-)

Comment: It can't be that bad? It's been good to me up until this point. It's the Big Nerd Ranch Guide to Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE` is just used to set the key for the `getBooleanExtra()` method, would be the same as setting the key in the method like this:

```
getBooleanExtra("com.britannia.android.quiz.answer_is_true", false);
```

The `false` is just the default value of the boolean which you are getting from the intent extras.  As long as the boolean has a correct value of true or false when passed through, then that false parameter will not be used.  (only if the boolean is undeclared or null will the default be used)

Answer (score 0):

the false is the default value if EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE is not found.

For questions like this, first check the javadoc  : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getBooleanExtra(java.lang.String,%20boolean)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the string EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE for? I don't understand it's purpose.

Some other activity is starting this one. That other activity needs to pass a `boolean` value to this `CheatActivity`. The way we do that in Android is by putting extras on the `Intent` that is used to start the activity. Extras are a key-value store; the `String` identified by the `EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE` is the key.

> And in the getBooleanExtra() it has two arguments, which is the string mentioned above and a value of false.

The second parameter is the default value; this will be returned by `getBooleanExtra()` if there is no value for the designated key.

> Why is it false?

Ask the author of the book. If the app is written correctly, that default value will never be used, as there will always be an extra for the designated key.

Comment: I see. I got really confused by the name `EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE` and the string it was given.

Comment: @BodyBingers: It is a rather bizarre name for an extra.

Answer (score 0):

EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE for parameter name.

When you Intent a class, you can send some parameters (name:value pair).

In your source, putExtra -> getBooleanExtra is doing that.

And getXXXExtra has default value if there is no name:value pair in parameters.

So,

mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);

is

set mAnswerIsTrue which "EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE"'s value. If not exist, set false.